# My android phone stops the application which I am trying to test from android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am a novice android app developer and have just started coding. I first developed a simple app with an image and some text and tested it on my android device; it worked just fine. I tried to deploy another app after changing the actionbar color but after that, the app force closes whenever I try to deploy. I have sony xperia e1 dual. Here are my files to which I have made the changes:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_converted"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#c62828</item>
        <item name="background">@color/velvetred</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

StackTrace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.love/app.love.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
    .....
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:124)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
    at app.love.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
    .....
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Can you add the stack trace?

Comment: Hey @ManuSunny , I added the stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are having this problem is because the activity you are trying to apply the theme to is extending `ActionBarActivity` which requires the `AppCompat` theme to be applied.

Change your `MainActivity` to extend `Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // code for your activity
}
```